# how to load different css files based on "store view"

Tags: magento2, css, store-view

I have two "store view"s and I want to only add a css file to one of the views. I have noticed that you must load css files in default_head_blocks.xml. here is what is want:

```
        <css src="css/style.css"/>
        <!--if storeview = fa-->
        <css src="css/theme-rtl.css"/>
        <!--endif-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You please refer this link may be help you.

And this link no create the two theme but store wise create the css please check this links :-

https://webkul-com.cdn.ampproject.org/v/s/webkul.com/blog/write-different-css-store-wise-magento2/amp/?usqp=mq331AQNKAGYAYakidD6rNbUOg%3D%3D&amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&ampshare=https%3A%2F%2Fwebkul.com%2Fblog%2Fwrite-different-css-store-wise-magento2%2F

Answer (score -1):

Include CSS store wise

> first store

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/store1/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

> second store

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/store2/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I want to do this with different "Store views" not stores. and I have currently an store installed. And Vendor fouler does not exist.

Comment: you are using a different theme for both stores?

Comment: No, theme and its Folder is same. I only want to add another CSS file to one of the store views